# Is it okay to supply two channel of isolated gate driver with same DC/DC converter?

Tags: power-electronics, isolation, gate-driving

I am planning to use NCP51560 isolated gate driver in my project. Here is the block diagram of the gate driver.

[image: NCP51560 Block Diagram]

I need isolation between primary and secondary side. I don't need an isolation between two channels of gate driver. Can I use same isolated DC/DC converter (or same supply) for VCCA and VCCB? I have read the datasheet and also take a look at the evaluation board but I couldn't find the information about that.

Here is the datasheet: [Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp51560-d.pdf)

Comment: I think you want VSSa and VSSb connected together.  Also VCCa and VCCb.  If both Sources are connected together then it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Can I use same isolated DC/DC converter (or same supply) for VCCA and
> VCCB.*

Provided that VSSA and VSSB are connected to the same common isolated converter then yes.